# Xaml vs C# runtime code performance in Xamarin.Forms android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Currently I am writing the Xamarin.Forms UI in C# code.

Is moving to Xaml will improve the performance ?

For example: I have a page that takes up to 2 seconds to load - it uses tableview with 100 different cell Views.

Comment: XAML is pre-compiled, it should not have any significant performance impact vs C#

Answer (score 3):

XAML can be [directly compiled into the intermediate Language](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/).

> XAMLC offers a number of a benefits:
>
> It performs compile-time checking of XAML, notifying the user of any errors.
>       It removes some of the load and instantiation time for XAML elements.
>       It helps to reduce the file size of the final assembly by no longer including .xaml files.
>
> XAMLC is disabled by default to ensure backwards compatibility. It can
>   be enabled at both the assembly and class level by adding the
>   XamlCompilation attribute.

As [Rafael Moura](https://forums.xamarin.com/profile/RafaelMoura) states in the following [quote](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44117/xaml-vs-programmatically) - **there shouldn't be a difference.**

> There is **no difference between the screen be done in XAML or C #**, when
>   compiled the result is just a DLL (apk, app, xap) with the
>   representation of the screen already pre-compiled, requiring only the
>   JIT. The difference is only in the level of organization code and
>   programming.

In my opinion you should always prefer XAML creating your UIs programatically in C#, as it is easier to maintain and organize.